# Run Apache Felix 4.0.2 in IntelliJ IDEA 11

Tags: java, intellij-idea, osgi, apache-felix

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585933/platform-is-not-supported-supported-when-trying-to-run-osgi-debug-target), IDEA uses [Osmorc](http://www.osmorc.org/) to run OSGi frameworks. It, in turn, uses [Pax Runner](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxrunner/Pax+Runner) to launch different framework implementations.

The toolchain in IDEA 11 can only run Apache Felix up to 3.0.2, but I have to run version 4.0.2. Is it possible? Do other OSGi framework launchers exist for IDEA?

Comment: I was never satisfied with osmorc in IDEA 10, so I ended up just launching org.apache.karaf.main.Bootstrap.main() as a regular java application. That approached works well enough, except that you can't rely on the IDE's compile button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure the OSGI frameworks that Osmorc uses from the plugin+ project settings.
I use IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.2 and Osmorc 1.4.2.

Here is a screenshot where I configure the OSGI container (at IDE Settings-->OSGi) to some local 
installation of Apache Felix 4.0.1.

[image: OSGi Framework Definiton]

You can also define your custom framework/container and then select the desired
OSGI framework to use at Project Settings-->OSGI as seen below:

[image: OSGi Framework selection]

In order to create Run configurations, you first need to create some OSGi facets.
Hopefully, you are also using maven and the maven-bundle-plugin which will greatly
reduce the amount of configuration you need to do(since OSmorc automatically syncs with your pom.xml), but even if you do not, you can manually edit the information for creating the bundles.

So, what you need to do next is create some OSGi facets. Go to Project "Structure-->Facets" 
and add a new OSGi facet for each bundle you wish to create. It you have automatic detection turned on, then the facets maybe already there. If not, then add them manually and then configure them as you see appropriate, like in the following example.

[image: Intellij IDEA OSGi Facet Configuration]

Finally edit your "Run Configurations" and add a new OSGi run configuration. 
Select the framework you wish to use and the bundles you wish to start as well as 
other parameters, like in the following example:

[image: Intellij IDEA OSGi Run Configuration]

Comment: How do you run an OSGi bundle after you configured the framework?

Comment: You create a run configuration as shown in the last step. With the Add-Button you can add the bundles that you want to run. They show in the table and you can select their start levels. Finally you start that run configuration using the "Play" or "Debug" buttons next to the run configuration flyout in the IntelliJ-Toolbar.

Comment: I know it's an old answer, but following the steps, when I run IntelliJ gives the error "Console requested but no shell bundles can be found"

Comment: @Vallentin please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEA-183907

Comment: Updating IntelliJ to latest version resolved the issue.